# Can't we use HAL_Delay() in ISR of stm32 F407VG

Tags: stm32, interrupt-handling, stm32f4discovery

I am new to stm32, I tried to implement an interrupt using the user button of stm32F407VG.
I added a `HAL_Delay()` inside the interrupt function.
When the button is pressed, the Interrupt service routine start executing but it never comes back to the `main()` function.

That's the part of the code which is responsible for the interrupt:

```
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
    if(GPIO_Pin==GPIO_PIN_0)
    {
        if(prev_val==false)
        {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14, 1);
            prev_val=true;
        }
        else
        {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14, 0);
            prev_val = false;
        }
        HAL_Delay(1000);

    }
}
```

Comment: have you called ```HAL_Init();``` in your main or init?

Comment: In the ```main()```.

Answer (score 2):

Take care: If using the default HAL settings provided by ST, the priority for SysTick IRQ is set to 15 when calling HAL_Init().

So you have to change that in the `stm32f7xx_hal_conf.h` file or by using the HAL_InitTick(TickPriority) function.

See also Usermanual [page 31](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjl9f3ilfHxAhXKhf0HHTPFDAUQFjAAegQIBRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Fuser_manual%2Fdm00189702-description-of-stm32f7-hal-and-lowlayer-drivers-stmicroelectronics.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3NBYT2xNRj3uv3S6TZ-RTv):

```
HAL_Delay(). this function implements a delay (expressed in milliseconds) using the SysTick timer.
Care must be taken when using HAL_Delay() since this function provides an accurate delay (expressed in
milliseconds) based on a variable incremented in SysTick ISR. This means that if HAL_Delay() is called from
a peripheral ISR, then the SysTick interrupt must have highest priority (numerically lower) than the
peripheral interrupt, otherwise the caller ISR is blocked.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to deal with it, my interrupt priority was 0 by default. And `HAL_Delay()` also has the priority 0.
So I reduced the priority of the external interrupt and set it to 1.
Now its working fine

Comment: think you're on the right track with the priority issue, i have posted you an answer ...

Comment: Can you demonstrate the code please.